# How to run my function only when button is pressed and held with pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I make a Button which executes the code under it only when the Button is pressed and held (let's say for one second) and stops when it is released?

````
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button '
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100, 70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what kind of function you want to execute while the button is pressed, but suppose you want to execute a function every second or so while the button is pressed.

In that case you could use a `QTimer` and connect the function you want to execute to the `QTimer.timeout` signal.

You could then use the `button.pressed` and `button.released` signals to start and stop a timer.

For example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button '
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

        self.counter = 0
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')

        # connect slots
        button.pressed.connect(self.on_press)
        button.released.connect(self.on_release)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setValue(0)

        vlayout.addWidget(button)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.progress)

        self.show()

    # function that should be run periodically while button is pressed
    def on_timeout(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.progress.setValue(self.counter)

    def on_press(self):
        self.progress.setValue(0)
        self.counter = 0
        self.timer.start(100)

    def on_release(self):
        self.timer.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = App()
    app.exec()
```